# Why is my cargo dependency not affecting the size of the bytecode?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

I have a barebones Rust project (specifically a CosmWasm smart contract, not sure if that matters). When I run `cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`, the uncompressed Wasm bytecode is about 1.7 MB.

Then I add the following dependency:
`evm = "1.18.0"`

and I add a patch:

```
[patch.crates-io]
evm = { path = "../../../evm" }
```

where the path leads to this project: https://github.com/neonlabsorg/evm

Then I re-run `cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`. I see that it is indeed building the EVM project and its dependencies. But when I look at the final uncompressed Wasm bytecode, it is still 1.7 MB! Why is the size of the bytecode still the same? Do I need to actually use the library in order for cargo to include the library in the bytecode?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you checking the final bytecode size? Also, do you use that dependency anywhere in your code? The linker might be removing it if it never gets used. You might be able to keep it from being optimized away by re-exporting the crate (Ex: `pub use enm;`) in your `lib.rs`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the size of the bytecode still the same? Do I need to actually use the library in order for cargo to include the library in the bytecode?

Yes. In general, only code that is *used* will appear in the final output of the compiler. There is (in normal circumstances) no reason to include unused items — they would enlarge the binary for no benefit.